# Intersperse list with a step

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list of posts `[Post1, Post2, Post3, Post4, ..., PostN] and I need to intersperse it with advertisement (basically, insert after N posts). For example:

```
step = 3
insert_advertisement(posts_list, advertisement, step) # Insert advertisement after 3 posts
```

Output:

`[Post1, Post2, Post3, advertisement, Post4, Post5, Post6, advertisement, ...]`

Is there nifty way to implement this with itertools? If not - then I'll appreciate any other solution.

Comment: There's nothing built-in to "intersperse" like that, but if you have a look through the [recipes in `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) you could combine and modify some to create what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a generator function:

```
>>> def insert_advertisement(posts_list, advertisement, step):
...     for i, post in enumerate(posts_list):
...         if i > 0 and i % step == 0:
...             yield advertisement
...         yield post
...
>>> list(insert_advertisement([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'ad', 3))
[1, 2, 3, 'ad', 4, 5, 6, 'ad', 7]
```

Comment: This is by far and away the most clear, maintainable and simplest solution to the problem.